# ColdFusion: how to get the filename of failed upload

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, cffile

I am trying to put the filename of a failed upload into an email, inside a try / catch, but I am not having any luck.

Based on this documentation - [FileUploadAll()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/fileuploadall.html) - I decided I am going to use error.

```
<cftry>
    <cffile destination="#FULLPATH#" action="upload" nameconflict="ERROR" continueOnError="true" filefield="FileName" />
    <cfcatch type="Any" >
        <cf_EmailHandler from="testmail@gmail.com" to="testmail@gmail.com" subject="Attachment Error - #BUILD_SEARCH.PROJECT_VERSION# #BUILD_SEARCH.BUILD_NUMBER#">
            <CFOUTPUT>
                Attachment Error - #BUILD_SEARCH.PROJECT_VERSION# #BUILD_SEARCH.BUILD_NUMBER#
                Cannot upload the following file:
                #FULLPATH# #ArrayLen(cffile.uploadAllErrors)#
            </CFOUTPUT>
        </cf_EmailHandler>
        <b>Error:</b>File already exists.
        <cfabort>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

I get the following error:

> Element UPLOADALLERRORS is undefined in CFFILE

So I try to fix that:

```
<cftry>
    <cffile destination="#FULLPATH#" action="upload" nameconflict="ERROR" Errors="errorResult" continueOnError="true" filefield="FileName" />
    <cfcatch type="Any" >
        <cf_EmailHandler from="testmail@gmail.com" to="testmail@gmail.com" subject="Attachment Error - #BUILD_SEARCH.PROJECT_VERSION# #BUILD_SEARCH.BUILD_NUMBER#">
            <CFOUTPUT>
                Attachment Error - #BUILD_SEARCH.PROJECT_VERSION# #BUILD_SEARCH.BUILD_NUMBER#
                Cannot upload the following file:
                #FULLPATH# #ArrayLen(errorResult.uploadAllErrors)#
            </CFOUTPUT>
        </cf_EmailHandler>
        <b>Error:</b>File already exists.
        <cfabort>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Then I am getting:

> Element UPLOADALLERRORS is undefined in ERRORRESULT.

Any idea on what I am doing wrong or another way to display the name of failed upload? Also I am using ColdFusion 11.

Comment: It is telling you there is no key named "UploadAllErrors" in that structure. See the linked docs under "errors" for a listing of the key names the errorResult variable will contain.

Comment: if I do just #errorResult#, I get Variable ERRORRESULT is undefined.

Comment: same thing if i do #errorResult.CLIENTFILE# or #errorResult[0].CLIENTFILE#, I get Variable ERRORRESULT is undefined. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The `cffile` tag only populates the `errors` attribute variable, when the error occurs while the upload is processed. If any unrelated error/exception occurs, you still end up in the catch and attempt to access the variable. Your error handling is too broad, don't catch all/`any`.

Comment: Why does it matter if a file already exists? Why not just use `nameConflict=makeunique`?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Bug report [CF-4204290](https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4204290) currently lists this issue as "To Fix".

**TL;DR;**

It's a documentation bug. The `continueOnError` attribute isn't supported with [action=upload](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-f/cffile-action-upload.html). Use [action=uploadAll](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-f/cffile-action-uploadall.html) instead. Keep in mind "uploadAll" supports multiple files, so results will be returned as an *array* of structures.

---

The reason it's not working is because the code is using the wrong "action". It should be **action="uploadAll"**. Since you're using `continueOnError="true"`, CF populates a structure with any errors that occur. By default it uses `CFFILE`, but you can specify a different variable name by using the `errors` attribute.

```
<cffile destination="c:/some/path/" 
    action="uploadAll" 
    nameconflict="ERROR" 
    continueOnError="true" 
    filefield="file_path" />
```

**Update:**

As pointed out in the comments, the documentation *does* say`continueOnError` is a supported attribute for [action=upload](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-f/cffile-action-upload.html). However, IMO it's a documentation bug. Adobe probably just copied the text from the action=uploadAll description.

Interestingly, the documentation for [FileUpload()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/fileupload.html), doesn't list that attribute at all. [Bug report CF-4199503](https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4199503) confirms the function version doesn't support it. Based on my tests below with CF11 and CF2016, I've concluded it's not supported in either version.

---

**Test Action=UploadAll**

Uploading a file that already exists in the destination directory, doesn't cause a hard error. CF populates the specified variable with error details and dumps them on screen:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(FORM, "submit")>
    <cffile destination="c:/temp" 
        action="uploadAll" 
        nameconflict="ERROR" 
        continueOnError="true" 
        errors="myErrors"
        filefield="file_path" />

    <cfdump var="#cffile#" label="cffile">
    <cfdump var="#myErrors#" label="errors">
</cfif>

<form  method="POST" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file_path">
    <input type="submit" name="test">
</form>
```

**Results:**
[image: Screenshot of Action UploadAll results]

**Test Action=Upload**

Change the action to `action="upload"` and the code fails. ColdFusion does NOT:

- Continue processing after the error .. or
- Populate `cffile` with error information ... or
- Create a result variable named by the `errors` attribute

**Results:**

[image: Screenshot of Action Upload Results]

*Note, omitting the optional `errors` attribute produces the same results. It works as expected when using action=uploadAll and fails with an error when using action=upload*

Comment: Fun fact: According to the [docs for action="upload"](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-f/cffile-action-upload.html), `uploadAllErrors` is also available there.

Comment: @Alex - An error in the documentation? I am shocked I tell you, shocked! ;-) Seriously though, I'm pretty sure it's wrong and they just copied the settings/text from the uploadAll description. In CF2016, the `continueOnError` setting doesn't actually work with "upload". Failures still throw an error and the details are added to the `cfcatch` structure.  Plus the description says "when uploading a file fails, the *remaining* files will not be uploaded. ". That doesn't even make sense with a single upload. There are no "remaining" files ;-) So ... I think it's just a documentation bug.

Answer (score 0):

In the form page, I captured the filename using JavaScript

```
<Input Name="FileName" type="file" size="#TEXT_AREA_WIDTH#"><br><br>
<Input type="Hidden" id="READ_FILE_NAME" name="READ_FILE_NAME" value="">
<Input type="Submit" name="Operation" value="Save" onclick="return validateAttachmentForm(this.form.FileName.value)">&nbsp;

function validateAttachmentForm(file_name)
{
  if (file_name.lastIndexOf("\\" != -1)) {
    var file_name = file_name.substring(file_name.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, file_name.length);
  }

  document.getElementById("READ_FILE_NAME").value = file_name;

  if(file_name != "")
  {
    return true;
  } else{

    alert('Please select a file to upload.')
    return false;
  } 
}
```

In the next page, I just display the filname passed in

```
<cftry>
    <cffile destination="#FULLPATH#" action="upload" nameconflict="ERROR" Errors="errorResult" continueOnError="true" filefield="FileName" />
    <cfcatch type="Any" >
        <cf_EmailHandler from="testmail@gmail.com" to="testmail@gmail.com" subject="Attachment Error - #BUILD_SEARCH.PROJECT_VERSION# #BUILD_SEARCH.BUILD_NUMBER#">
            <CFOUTPUT>
                Attachment Error - #BUILD_SEARCH.PROJECT_VERSION# #BUILD_SEARCH.BUILD_NUMBER#
                Cannot upload the following file:
                #FULLPATH#\#form.READ_FILE_NAME#
            </CFOUTPUT>
        </cf_EmailHandler>
        <b>Error:</b>File already exists.
        <cfabort>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Comment: It's a bug, but no need for javascript hacks. Just use action=uploadAll instead.